# javascript replace escaped " to work with Json parse

Tags: javascript, regex, json

This is the input of javacript function that arise error after Json.parse
I know double escape string is working with JSON.parse, but how to convert current string to that one... I have tried couple of things, but couln't make it work.

```
        pVis = '[{"Name":"Ecz., - \"     Europharma\" \" -\"","Id":"402872"}]';
        console.log('before replace'+pVis);
        pVis = pVis.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");
        //pVis = '[{"Name":"Ecz., - \\"     Europharma\\" \\" -\\"","Id":"402872"}]';
        console.log('after replace'+pVis);
        pVisitedsJson = JSON.parse(pVis);
```

Comment: Why does "pVis" start off as a string like that? Why not just create a JavaScript object literal?

Comment: `pVis = '[{"Name":"Ecz., - \"     Europharma\" \" -\"","Id":"402872"}]';` will make `pVis` as `'[{"Name":"Ecz., - "     Europharma" " -"","Id":"402872"}]'` without backslashes.

Comment: You need to use `pVis = '[{"Name":"Ecz., - \\"     Europharma\\" \\" -\\"","Id":"402872"}]'`

Comment: @Pointy actually it's coming from android as a parameter, that's why...

Comment: @anubhava yes but how to convert that's the question??

Comment: You're mistaken on conversion part. When you original string do you see backslashes? It will be printed as `'[{"Name":"Ecz., - "     Europharma" " -"","Id":"402872"}]'` without backslashes so what and how're you going to convert them?

Comment: @anubhava yes I cannot see on console, but I think that's because of console. It's there in original string, isn't it? now confused

Comment: You need to understand that these 2 assignments: `s='ab\"c'` and `s='ab"c'` are **exactly same**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's interpreting ' character as escaped, it's impossible for me catch and change it on javascript side. So, I changed from the source.